# How to get movable graphical items inside a QGraphicsItemGroup?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

My goal is to write a software that displays two movable disks that live inside the same `QGraphicsItemGroup`. I'd like to use `QGraphicsItemGroup` because in this way each disk can access the position of the other. To make the objects movable, I use the flag `ItemIsMovable` which unfortunately doesn't seem to work inside a `QGraphicsItemGroup` The following program exemplifies my issue:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem,\ 
    QApplication, QGraphicsItemGroup, QGraphicsEllipseItem


class MyDisk(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, top_left_x, top_left_y, radius, color):
        super().__init__(top_left_x, top_left_y, radius, radius)
        self.setBrush(color)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)


class MyGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.disk1 = MyDisk(50, 50, 20, Qt.red)
        self.disk2 = MyDisk(150, 150, 20, Qt.red)
        self.addToGroup(self.disk1)
        self.addToGroup(self.disk2)
        # self.setFlag(QGraphicsItemGroup.ItemIsMovable)


class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red disks are not movable')
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250)
        self.group = MyGroup()
        self.scene.addItem(self.group)
        self.scene.addItem(MyDisk(150, 50, 20, Qt.green))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    f = MyView()
    f.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is that the green disk (not in the group) is movable but the two red disks (in the group) are not. How can I make the two red disks movable? Note that setting the flag `ItemIsMovable` inside `MyGroup` doesn't solve the problem because the red disks would then move together (you can try this by uncomment the comment in the code).

Comment: Any item that belongs to a QGraphicsItemGroup can not be moved independently, so you can not move it directly, what you do is move the whole group, but in your case I think that is what you do not want. You argue that you want to use a QGraphicsItemGroup because you know the position of the other item, but I do not see any code where you use that information. If you showed how you use that information, we might be able to give you an alternative instead of using a QGraphicsItemGroup.

Comment: Thanks for that eyllanesc. I would like to write a program that shows two disks that can be separately moved although maintaining their relative distance fixed. In other words, each disk is constrained to move in a circle which center is given by the other disk, and the radius by the distance between the two disks. Any thought about how should I implement such solution?